# python - Multiprocessing and PoolManager: urllib3 Error: Can't pickle <function PoolManager

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, urllib3

I was trying to create a small program that could use a couple of threads to run a process in a class/function.

This Object has an instance of `urllib3.PoolManager(..)` and it seems to be a problem when launching the thread. See error after code.
It something hanging when the line `self.manager = urllib3.PoolManager(num_pools = 10)` that is to create an instance of PoolManager that will be used later on.

What is the issue here and what am I missing?

**Code**:

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process, freeze_support
import urllib3

class myObj:

    def __init__(self):
    #problem in line below
#==== > self.manager = urllib3.PoolManager(num_pools = 10)
        x = 5 #something

    def double_id(self, val):
        return 2*val

# Functions referenced by tasks
def callMyObj(obj):
    myObj = obj[0]
    rev_val = myObj.double_id(random.random())
    return rev_val
    #return obj.double_id

#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

# Function run by worker processes
def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = func(args)
        output.put(result)


#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4
    TASKS1 = [(callMyObj, (myObj(), 'double_id')) for i in range(10)]

    # Create queues
    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()

    #-Submit tasks, Start worker processes, Get Unordered results
    for task in TASKS1: task_queue.put(task)
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()
    for i in range(len(TASKS1)):
        print('>> done', done_queue.get())
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES): task_queue.put('STOP') #stop childs
```

**Error**:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in
>   dumps
>       cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
>   _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle . at 0x7f9752ae3840>: attribute
>   lookup  on urllib3.poolmanager failed

Comment: I suspect the issue is that while a connection pool can be shard between threads, it cannot be shared between processes/subprocesses. You'll need to make a separate pool for each process, or use threads instead.

Comment: Wow, I see. Many thanks